# How can I allow my "viewers" to sort Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, collaboration, file-sharing

When I share a Google Sheet with view-only permissions, viewers can sort the sheet by the values in a given column, but doing so produces errors, indicating that

> "the formula in cell XXX is referencing a range in the active filter that is not in the same row".

Is there no way for "viewers" to sort Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Viewers in theory can currently:

- Use existent filters and duplicate them temporarily (won't be added to file)
- Apply new filters temporarily
- See all notes
- Change Zoom
- Search
- Sort (creates new temporary filter)

If not specifically deactivated they can also:

- Print
- Copy
- Download

Nevertheless, making a fast test, it appears **nowadays there's a problem for viewers** to use existing filters, it seems these are being activated but not really. I've just reported it.

Answer (score -1):

If the Sheet is View-Only, then you shouldn't need the formulas, filters or otherwise.

Just create a new Sheet, or even a new Spreadsheet that has the values and formatting, but not the formulas.

Then your viewers can sort and view, without the formulas getting messed up.

Comment: The sheet is not frozen. For that I'd email a PDF.

Comment: Kinda hard to sort a table in a PDF. By giving the user a view-only copy, you can make your filters work independently of the way the page or sheet is sorted. You could add a button or menu item to refresh the page if the data is dynamic. Could you edit your question to include an example of the dataset you are working with and explain what viewers would want to see?

Comment: Can you provide me with an example of the behavior you want to avoid?